# Regex on string split

Tags: java, regex, string, split

need some regex help on string split.

- Key1|Key2||Key4| |Key6|"Key7|7A"
- Key1||Key3|Key4| ||Key7
- Key1||Key3|"Key4|4A"| ||"Key7|7A"

I want the result to always be splitted into 7 elements in a list. It could be null or space or could have a pipe delimited value.

Here is the sample expected  output for line #3

- Key1
- // null
- Key3
- Key4|4A
- // space
- // null
- Key7|7A

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have been trying with the following matcher, but doesnt seem to work correctly.

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([^\"]\\S*|\".+?\")|").matcher(key);

Comment: What is your basis of split , is it pipe ? if its pipe you can split by  pipe , add the first six string array positions and then as seventh add the rest .

Comment: Anyone regex expert can show me how to parse the line correctly please?

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
((?<=\|)()(?=\|))|("[A-Za-z0-9|]+")|([A-Za-z0-9 ]+)
```

output:

- >Key1<
- ><
- >Key3<
- >"Key4|4A"<
- > <
- ><
- >"Key7|7A"<

I put every string between >< brackets like : >(string)<, to make space and null visible.